# creating a custom form element in Zend_Form

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I'm attempting to create a custom form field in `Zend_Form` to store a snippet of HTML that is required by SWFUpload(for the purposes of a flash file uploader).

I've tried following a few different tutorials but i'm getting pretty confused, so far this is what i have:

```
/application/forms/elements/SwfUpload.php
                            SwfUploadHelper.php
```

These files are autoloaded in Bootstrap (well, SwfUpload.php certainly is) .

SwfUpload.php:

```
class Custom_Form_Element_SwfUpload extends Zend_Form_Element
{
    public $helper = 'swfUpload';
}
```

SwfUploadHelper.php:

```
class Custom_Form_Helper_SwfUpload extends Zend_View_Helper_FormElement
{
    public function swfUpload()
    {
        $html = '<div id="swfupload-control">
                    <p>Upload upto 5 image files(jpg, png, gif), each having maximum size of 1MB(Use Ctrl/Shift to select multiple files)</p>
                    <input type="button" id="button" />
                    <p id="queuestatus" ></p>
                    <ol id="log"></ol>
                </div>';
        return $html;
    }
}
```

when i instantiate this class like this:

```
class Form_ApplicationForm extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $custom = new Custom_Form_Element_SwfUpload('swfupload');
        // etc etc
```

I get this error:

> Message: Plugin by name 'SwfUpload'
>   was not found in the registry; used
>   paths: Zend_View_Helper_:
>   Zend/View/Helper/:/home/mysite/application/views/helpers/

Is it the case that it's expecting my helper to be in "`home/mysite/application/views/helpers/`"? I've tried creating the same helper in there with the filename "SwfUpload.php" but the error remains. Not sure i this is purely a filename/path issue or something else.

thanks.

Comment: Here is a question like yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056737/add-html-placeholder-into-zendform/2056841

Comment: thats actually my question too, not intending to spam but its difficult on stackoverflow when the question kind of changes tact like this one has. that was more a case of whats the theory, this is more a case of troubleshooting specifics.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is what i ended up with, hope it helps someone else:

in `/application/forms/elements/SwfUpload.php`

```
class Custom_Form_Element_SwfUpload extends Zend_Form_Element
{
    public $helper = 'swfUpload'; # maps to method name in SwfUpload helper
    public function init()
    {
        $view = $this->getView();
        $view->addHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH.'/views/helpers/', 'Custom_Form_Helper');
    }
}
```

in `/application/views/helpers/SwfUpload.php`

```
class Custom_Form_Helper_SwfUpload extends Zend_View_Helper_FormElement
{
    public function init(){} 

    public function swfUpload()
    {
        $html = '<div id="swfupload-control">
                    <p>Upload upto 5 image files(jpg, png, gif), each having maximum size of 1MB(Use Ctrl/Shift to select multiple files)</p>
                    <input type="button" id="button" />
                    <p id="queuestatus" ></p>
                    <ol id="log"></ol>
                </div>';
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[API Docs for Zend_Form_Element](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Form/Element/Zend_Form_Element.html)

```
void __construct (string|array|Zend_Config $spec, [ $options = null])

    * string|array|Zend_Config $spec
    * $options

$spec may be:

    * string: name of element
    * array: options with which to configure element
    * Zend_Config: Zend_Config with options for configuring element

    * throws: Zend_Form_Exception if no element name after initialization
    * access: public
```

See what it throws? Try

```
$custom = new Custom_Form_Element_SwfUpload('upload');
```

Comment: just noticed that myself, d'oh.